# fast application of a function with multiple argument to variables of a large data.table

Tags: r

I am currently working on a data.table of 2M rows and 14 columns (v1 to v14)

I also have a function  `PUC(x,k,q,int_,tx,m1,mr,a,g_p,lic,tabl)` that takes all his arguments in the data.table

**PUC**:

```
PUC <- function(x,k,q,int_,tx,m1,mr,a,g_p,lic,tabl){ return(PUCdec(x,k,q,int_,tx,m1,mr,a,g_p,tabl)+PUClic(k,q,int_,tx,m1,mr,a,g_p,lic)) }
```

**PUCdec**:

```
PUCdec <-function(x,k,q,int_,tx,m1,mr,a,g_p,tabl){return(PUPdec(x,k,q,int_,tx,m1,mr,tabl)/(1-a-g_p))}
```

**PUPdec**:

```
PUPdec <-function(x,k,q,int_,tx,m1,mr,tabl){
v = 1/(1+i) 
pupd=sum(Kr(k,0:(m1 -1),q,int_ ,tx,m1,mr)*(v^((1+(0:(m1 -1)))/q)*(dx(x+floor((0:(m1 -1))/q),tabl)/lx(x,tabl))))     
  return(pupd/q)}
```

**Kr**:

```
 Kr <- function(k,r,q,int_,tx,m1,mr){
  jq=0
  k0=0
  jq <- int_*(1+tx)/q
  kr = fifelse((r <= (m1-mr)), k*(1+jq)^r,fifelse((r > m1), 0, k*((1+jq)^(m1-mr))*(1+jq)^(r-m1+mr)+ Ar(k,r,q,int_,tx, m1,mr)*(1-(1+jq)^(r-m1+mr))/jq))
  return(kr)}
```

**Ar**:

```
 Ar <- function(k,r,q,int_,tx,m1,mr){
  jq=0
  jq <- int_*(1+tx)/q
 ar<- fifelse(r<= (m1-mr),0,(jq*k*(1+jq)^(m1-mr))/(1-(1+jq)^(-mr)))
  return(ar)}
```

I use this code to calculate

```
F8[, p:=mapply(PUC, v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10,v11)]
```

but i find it too slower.

Please, Is there a way to do it faster ?

Comment: Why are you using `mapply`? Is `PUC` not vectorized? If that's the case, you are out of luck.

Comment: I vectorize but but it still takes long time to give the result   `PUCv <- Vectorize(PUC)`  PUCv(v1,v2,v3,v4,v5,v6,v7,v8,v9,v10,v11)

Comment: Vectorize just calls mapply.

Comment: In R idiom a "vectorized" function is one that can act elementwise across one or more arguments, usually by calling compiled C, C++ or Fortran code that is optimized to work elementwise. For example `+` is described as vectorized because you can call `c(1,2,3,4) + 1`, but also because + calls C++ code that acts elementwise.  Wrapping a function in `Vectorize` just composes a call to `mapply`, it won't improve the function's internal performance, and if the function is already vectorized it reduces performance. Can you share the function definition of `PUC`?

Comment: PUC is a combination of several functions that I send to you below :  **PUC**        
 `PUC <- function(x,k,q,int_,tx,m1,mr,a,g_p,lic,tabl){
  return(PUCdec(x,k,q,int_,tx, m1,mr,a, g_p,tabl)+PUClic(k,q,int_,tx,m1,mr,a,g_p,lic))
}`

Comment: `PUCdec <-function(x,k,q,int_,tx,m1,mr,a,g_p,tabl){
  return(PUPdec(x,k,q,int_,tx,m1,mr,tabl)/(1-a-g_p))
}`

Comment: `PUPdec <-function(x,k,q,int_,tx,m1,mr,tabl){
  v = 1/(1+i) #Contrairement a la note technique
  pupd=sum(Kr_vec(k,0:(m1 -1),q,int_ ,tx,m1,mr)*(v^((1+(0:(m1 -1)))/q)*(dx(x+floor((0:(m1 -1))/q),tabl)/lx(x,tabl))))
  return(pupd/q)
}`

Comment: `Kr_vec <- Vectorize(Kr, vectorize.args = "r")`

Comment: (1) If the function definitions in your comments are relevant to the question, please [edit] your question and include them there: comments are easily skipped by readers or hidden by the interface when there are many comments. (2) At the base of your function stack is `Kr_vec` which calls `Vectorize`. As bcarlsen and Roland have said, the `Vectorize` function does not improve the performance of a function that was not designed with R's efficient "vectorization" in mind. I don't know the `Kr` function (and you don't say where you get it), so there's not much we can do to help.

Comment: Hi @r2evans, Think you for your comment, I edit my question.

Comment: Maybe with a reproducible example (e.g., a _small_ simulated dataset that can grow and `PUClic` being defined), you may get more responses. Regardless, this may be better at Code Review or consulting with someone who can refactor your code. I am removing [tag:data.table] tag as this is more of a question of "How do I improve performance of this function" rather than something dealing with [tag:data.table]